# Unary negation of unsigned integer 4

Tags: c

If x is an unsigned int type is there a difference in these statements:

```
return (x & 7);
```

and

```
return (-x & 7);
```

I understand negating an unsigned value gives a value of `max_int - value`. But is there a difference in the return value (i.e. true/false) among the above two statements under any specific boundary conditions OR are they both same functionally?

Comment: You could test for yourself rather easily, couldn't you? In general, yes, there's a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned neg7(unsigned x) { return -x & 7; }

static unsigned pos7(unsigned x) { return +x & 7; }

int main(void)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        printf("%u: pos %u; neg %u\n", i, pos7(i), neg7(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Test results:

```
0: pos 0; neg 0
1: pos 1; neg 7
2: pos 2; neg 6
3: pos 3; neg 5
4: pos 4; neg 4
5: pos 5; neg 3
6: pos 6; neg 2
7: pos 7; neg 1
```

For the specific case of 4 (and also 0), there isn't a difference; for other values, there is a difference. You can extend the range of the input, but the outputs will produce the same pattern.

Comment: This also shows that, contrary to what the OP believes, the `&` operator does *not* return a boolean true/false.

Comment: Just curious... why did you mark those functions as `static`?

Comment: @RastaJedi: Because they aren't used outside this file, and there isn't a header to declare them, and the compilation options I use (`gcc -O3 -g -std=c11   -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror …`) demand declarations for non-static functions other than `main()`.  I'd probably add `inline` these days (and `static inline` is a heap easier to understand than the alternatives).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so if you had a prototype above main and the definitions below it wouldn't complain if it was non-`static`? Exactly which `-W` flag causes that? What's its rationale?

Comment: @RastaJedi: Yes, if I put a prototype declaration before the definition of a non-static version, there'd be no problem (beyond two extra lines of verbosity).  It's one of `-Wmissing-prototypes` (probably) or `-Wstrict-prototypes` (perhaps).  Using the options ensures that functions are properly declared.  All functions should be static unless used outside their source file.  Non-static functions should be declared in a header used both in the file that defines the function and in all the files that use the function.  This ensures consistency.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler why should functions be static unless used outside that translation unit?

Comment: @RastaJedi: Two reasons (at least).  (1) Namespace control: especially in files that don't contain `main()` — unlike this one — you should not expose any symbols that are not necessary outside the source file.  It reduces the possibilities of conflict with other code (and visible symbols should be declared in a header).  (2) Optimization: if the function is static, then the compiler knows it can see all the uses of the function, and it might treat them as inline even without the `inline` keyword.  If the function is not `static`, it has to generate the function in case some other file uses it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler if I was forced to guess two reasons why I might have come up with those as guesses but still this is why I love SO because I literally learn something new about C every day.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, negating an `unsigned int` value produces `UINT_MAX - original_value + 1`. (For example, `0` remains `0` under negation). The alternative way to describe negation is full inversion of all bits followed by increment.

It is not clear why you'd even ask this question, since it is obvious that basically the very first example that comes to mind — an `unsigned int` value `1` — already produces different results in your expression. `1u & 7` is `1`, while `-1u & 7` is `7`. Did you mean something else, by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

If you ask specifically for true/false (i.e. is zero / not zero) and two's complement then there is indeed no difference. (You do however return not just a simple truth value but allow different bit patterns for `true`. As long as the caller does not distinguish, that is fine.)

Consider how a two's complement negation is formed: invert the bits then increment. Since you take only the least significant bits, there will be no carry in for the increment. This is a necessity, so you can't do this with anything but a range of least significant bits.

Let's look at the two cases:

First, if the three low bits are zero (for a `false` equivalent). Inverting gives all ones, incrementing turns them to zero again. The fourth and more significant bits might be different, but they don't influence the least significant bits and they don't influence the result since they are masked out. So this stays.

Second, if the three low bits are not all zero (for a `true` equivalent). The only way this can change into `false` is when the increment operation leaves them at zero, which can only happen if they were all ones before, which in turn could only happen if they were all zeros before the inversion. That can't be, since that is the first case. Again, the more significant bits don't influence the three low bits and they are masked out. So the result does not change.

But again, this only works when the caller considers only the truth value (all bits zero / not all bits zero) and when the mask allows a range of bits starting from the least significant without a gap.

Comment: While reading I don't know if it was just extremely detailed but it seems like you made it sound more complicate than it really is, but I was still able to follow and this is still a great answer, +1. Pretty much is the wording to back and describe @JonathanLeffler's answer.